# How to Make Extruded/Drawn Vertices part of Face it Was Drawn On?

Tags: vertices, faces

I took a vertex from an existing face and extruded it to draw new lines onto that face. The face is perfectly aligned to one axis/plane and I limited the vertices to that plane of existence when extruding so I know they're perfectly aligned with the face.

I had kind of hoped that they would then become a part of that face but I cannot seem to join <kbd>J</kbd> them with other vertices of that face.

Can this be done? And how?

Or else, what is the easier way to do what I am trying to do? I really hope my only option is not to split the existing lines hundreds of times and join them all together and split the new lines just to get vertices where I want them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the knife tool, shortcut <kbd>K</kbd>, this allows you to cut the face any way you want.

Comment: Ah! Perfect! So instead of extruding the vertex over and over, I just start cutting from it. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Do you by chance know of a good tutorial that would show how to make a custom object from scratch? Like, in my case, I want to make a statue. Does it work best to modify spheres and cubes and add them all together? Does it work better to start with 2D on the bottom and work up like a 3D printer? What do the professionals do? I've been doing the first method for the most part....

Comment: All objects are "custom" from anyone else's point of view. There are literally tons of tutorials over the internet, just google whatever it is you want. What you should be more concerned about though is modelling with [good topology](http://topologyguides.com) to avoid any troubles down the road. That means a quad based mesh and no Knife tools nor Booleans

Comment: Ah, if you could link an example of what you are trying to accomplish I could better direct you, if what you are trying to create is an organic model you should look into sculpting.

Usually you want a rough base mesh, made from an initial cube.
Tough if this are your first steps into 3D I'd recommend first familiarizing yourself with the environment, and reading, just a bit, on good practices.

If you provide more details, such as if you are working alone, what you expect and how the object is going to be used I can better direct you to some resources.